# Uncaught ReferenceError: $result is not defined

Tags: javascript, php, json

The below script means for cross domain and pull out the JSON result for the select menu.  Currently the CURL able to echo out the $result but unable to display in the select menu with console log error: Uncaught ReferenceError: the $result is not defined.  I need help on diagnosing this matter.

```php
<?php
$data_string = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
$ch = curl_init('https://xxxxxxx.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_string);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Content-Length: ' . strlen($data_string)
));

$result = curl_exec($ch);

echo ($result);
?>
    
    <script>
    
    let dropdown = $('#title-dropdown');
    
    dropdown.empty();
    dropdown.append('<option selected="true" disabled>Choose Title</option>');
    dropdown.prop('selectedIndex', 0);
    
    const url = $result;
    
    $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
      $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
        dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.description).text(entry.display_name));
      })
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: You can't use PHP variables directly in JavaScript! Try like this: `const url = '<?php echo $result; ?>';`

Comment: It gave me this console log error msg after adding in: GET localhost/[object%20Object] 404 (Not Found)

Comment: `$.getJSON(url, function (data)` make a complete HTTP GET request. The variable `url` doesn't contain a URL, this variable contains already the JSON object!

Answer (score 0):

You aren't outputting the PHP $result variable to the Javascript, you're telling javascript to look for a variable that doesn't exist. Try

```
const url = '<?php echo $result ?>';
```

it's been a while since I've done any PHP but that should at least put you on the right track if it isn't 100% correct.

Comment: It gave me this console log error msg after adding in

Answer (score -1):

Change this

```
const url = $result;

$.getJSON(url, function (data) {
  $.each(data, function (key, entry) {
    dropdown.append($('<option></option>').attr('value', entry.description).text(entry.display_name));
  })
});
```

to this:

```
const json = $.parseJSON('<?php echo $result; ?>');
var result = json.result;
for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
  for (var key in result[i]) {
    console.log('KEY: ' + key + 'VALUE: ' + result[i][key]);
  }
}
```

Comment: The above result gave me a drop down menu but the contain is blank......no error in console log.

Comment: Show an sample of your JSON object

Comment: {[{"display_name": "xxxxxx", "description": "xxxxxx", "package_count": 0, "created": "xxxxxx", "name": "xxxxxx", "is_organization": true, "state": "active", "image_url": "", "type": "organization", "title": "xxxxxx", "num_followers": 0, "id": "xxxxxx", "approval_status": "xxxxxx"},
{"display_name": yyyyyy"description": "yyyyyy",  "package_count": 0, "created": "yyyyyy", "name": "yyyyyy", "is_organization": true, "state": "active", "image_url": "", "type": "organization", "title": "yyyyyy", "num_followers": 0, "id": "yyyyyy", "approval_status": "yyyyyy"}]}

Comment: That is not a valid JSON!

Comment: u means whole set? wait a minute.

Comment: Yes, a valid JSON doesn't start with {[

Comment: {"result": [
{"display_name": "A", "description": "A", "image_display_url": "", "package_count": 0, "created": "2018-04-19T09:14:32.424164", "name": "A", "is_organization": true, "state": "active", "image_url": "", "type": "organization", "title": "A"}, 

{"display_name": "B", "description": "B", "image_display_url": "", "package_count": 2, "created": "2018-04-11T16:33:19.983003", "name": "B", "is_organization": true, "state": "active", "image_url": "", "type": "organization", "title": "B"}]}

Comment: I have modified my code example above. Just change the console.log() to whatever you want to do with `key` and `result[i][key]` (value)

Comment: It giving Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list